# trouble unpickling a file _pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered, but no persistent_load function was specified

Tags: python, pickle

I am working to process data for a bioinformatics program (https://github.com/twopin/CAMP/tree/master/CAMP_pytorch).

I am planning to unpickle the data/code used by the software author to troubleshoot our workflow. I have downloaded the pickle files, unziped the pickle files and got the following error when trying to load the pickle files:

How best to proceed?

```
import pickle

with open("model_full_ckpts_0.pkl", 'rb') as f:
    loaded = pickle.load(f) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
_pickle.UnpicklingError: A load persistent id instruction was encountered,
but no persistent_load function was specified.
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you're seeing happens because the pickled file you're trying to load was created using a custom class or object, and that class or object is not defined in your current code.

Here's what I would do:

Identify Custom Classes:
Check the bioinformatics program's documentation or code to find out if it uses any special classes or objects when saving data.

Define Custom Classes:
If you find any custom classes, create simple placeholder versions of those classes in your code.

Load Pickle File:
Try loading the pickled file again after defining the necessary classes.